# Why there is no perfectly transmitting surface?

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

My teacher was teaching us about the process radiation in heat transfer. He told us there are

1. Perfectly absorbing surface i.e. Black body.
2. Perfectly reflecting surface.

Then I asked him about *perfectly transmitting surface*. But he answered it doesn't exist . Can anybody tell me why it doesn't exist?

Comment: Nothing really perfect exist in this world.. even a perfect black body or a perfectly reflecting surface are idealizations.

Comment: I can see no reason why a perfectly transmitting surface could not be postulated for a problem, just like the others. A model would be the boundary between one region of vacuum and an adjacent one.

Comment: @Peter , I myself have thought that. But I couldn't get any reference. Can you provide please ? Also if there is why is it not given anywhere?

Comment: I'm not an expert, and I haven't searched for it. I would guess though that the reason a perfect transmitting surface is not used is that nothing of interest happens there. After all, how much interest is there in radiation passing directly from one region of empty space to another?